# Applescript code to find path to Desktop picture in Desktop 2

Tags: applescript, desktop

I need an applescript that will find the path to the desktop picture used in Desktop 2. As this isn't the current desktop the code below doesn't work.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set DesktopPath to desktop picture as string
end tell
```

Is there anyway to easily automatically find the path to the picture in desktop 2?

runnning el capitan

Comment: From MacOS 10.12 Sierra on, a lot of things have changed in System. I am using High Sierra 10.13.6 and there is no "desktop 2" in a list of EVERY desktop, but only the currently used one. . . . To get `desktop picture` I use: . . . `tell application "System Events" to set PicsName to (picture of current desktop as text)` . . . which will deliver: . . . `"/Library/Desktop Pictures/Aqua Blue1024.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
tell application "System Events"
set tlst to a reference to every desktop
--set picture of item 1 of tlst to newtop  -- display 1
--set picture of item 2 of tlst to newtop -- display 2
set z to (picture of item 2 of tlst) as text
end tell
return z
```

The commented out lines are for setting desktop pic on one display or the other. newtop is obviously preset, or the result of

```
set newtop to choose file
```

Comment: System Events got an error: Can’t get item 2 of every desktop. Invalid index. I seem to get this error?

Comment: I'm not seeing that error. OS X 10.11.3 Script Editor 2.81 AppleScript 2.5  Have you got the "set z..." bit inside your tell block? I can get errors similar to what you describe if I move that line outside the tell.

Comment: The code is copied as is. I'm checking on another computer atm. Edit: On another computer with the exact script it comes up with the same error.

Comment: I recall possibly seeing this script to be used for different desktops on different monitors. The desktops I mean are the ones with numbers when pressing f3 next to the dashboard.